# define a variable in a query then use it within the same query?

Tags: php, mysql

i made a class connection that will handle the query also then return all the data needed from the database :

the problem is how can define a variable within the query that will handle one value that i want to insert it in the same query !!

```
$invoice_connection_add = new connection("
SET @myvar := select `brand_name` from `brands` where `brand_code` = $_POST[brand_code]
insert into `invoices` (`brand_code`, `brand_name`, `quantity`, `price`,`date`, `salesman`) values ('$_POST[brand_code]',@myvar, '$_POST[quantity]', '$_POST[price]', '$_POST[date]', '$_SESSION[username]');","insert_update");
```

Comment: hard to understand. do you want a parameterized query? or some other construct - like a subselect?

Comment: single quote missing in all $_POST

Comment: Could you not just post the brand name instead of the code?

Comment: that's what i need " $_Post['brand_name'] " , and i have to get it from another table where brand_code = $_POST['brand_code'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody else seems to be answering so I'll give it a shot - you can do something like this. You might need to play with the quotations and stuff a little bit but it'll give you an idea of what you want to do.

```
INSERT INTO invoices (all your columns) 
  SELECT '$_POST[brand_code]', brand_name, '$_POST[quantity]', 
  '$_POST[price]', '$_POST[date]', '$_SESSION[username]' 
  FROM `brands` 
  WHERE `brand_code` = $_POST[brand_code]
```

Comment: well yes i thought about this but can i do the following :INSERT INTO invoices (all your columns) values ((select brand_name from brands where brands.brandcode = $_post[brand code]), $_post[], $post, $post ); i made this but it's taking select statement as text and insert it in the db

Comment: @user1892114 Pretty sure you dont put it in values()

Comment: there's a backtick at the end of the code. can't remove because SO insists at least 6 chars are replaced

Comment: thank you once again : ) , i spent 3 hours trying to do such tricky code but my brain is halted : )